# KDE Login screen for 2 monitor

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, kde

I'm wondering if is possible to remove one of the login screens under Kubuntu 15.10, I'm working with kubuntu and 2 monitors, and each time when I start my PC both monitor are showing the login window and I just want one login window.. There's posibble to make something like that?

Best regards

ML